# Conditionally convert a decimal value to integer

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
create table #Temp
(
    id int,
    Volume decimal(18,3)
)

insert into #Temp(id,Volume)values(1,10)
insert into #Temp(id,Volume)values(2,10.2)


id  Volume
-----------------
1   10.000
2   10.200


Declare @Type as int
set @Type=1


 select Id,Convert(varchar(10),CASE WHEN @Type=1 THEN CAST(Volume AS INT)
 ELSE Volume  END) AS Quantity from #Temp
```

It is showing a result like this

```
id  Volume
-----------------
1   10.000
2   10.000
```

But I want result like this when type is 1 then result should be in integer format:

```
id  Volume
-----------------
1   10
2   10
```

on else condition (@Type rather than 1) I want result like this

```
    id  Volume
    -----------------
    1   10.000
    2   10.200
```

I have tried this query

```
select Id,Convert(varchar(10),CASE WHEN @Type=1 THEN CAST(Volume AS INT) 
ELSE Volume  END) AS Quantity from #Temp
```

Comment: You'll need to write two separate queries and gate those behind an `IF`. T-SQL only allows static types for its columns, so you cannot conditionally switch types within a query.

Comment: @ Panagiotis Kanavos it's not working sir....

Comment: What isn't working? Frankly, why do that on the server at all? When you return an integer you're actually rounding. So why not round and still return a decimal?

Comment: This sounds like you should be using the presentation layer to control the display format, rather than SQL Server Dynamically change the data type of the column.

Comment: Side Note: SQL Server has been u supported for over a year now and you should really be looking at upgrade paths as soon as you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for you.

```
 select Id, (CASE WHEN @Type=1 THEN convert(varchar(10),convert(int,volume))
 ELSE convert(varchar(10),Volume)  END) AS Quantity from #Temp
```

When @type is 1, the result will be 10 for both values. Otherwise it will be exact value in the table.

Comment: I'm really not a fan of returning numerical data as a string based data type. Strings and numerical data are very different. For example `'10'` has a **lower** value than `'2'`. Returning a string can have unexpected results when using numerical data.